# How to store a digit string into an arbitrary large integer?

Tags: c, math, digits, arbitrary-precision

Let `ib` be the input base and `ob` the output base. `str` is the ASCII representation of some arbitrary large integer `x`. I need to define `f` such as:

```
f(str="1234567890", ib=10, ob=16) = {4, 9, 9, 6, 0, 2, 13, 2}
```

... where the return type of `f` is an `int` array containing the base `ob` digits of this integer. We assume that `2 >= ob <= MAX_INT` and `2 >= ib <= 10`, and `str` will always be a valid string (no negative needed).

Comment: What does a zero-terminated int array look like? In your example I would guess that `{4, 9, 9, 6, 0, 2, 13, 2, 0}` would be `{4, 9, 9, 6}` if it was zero-terminated.

Comment: @Welbog, well, intuitively, I would use logarithms to deal with that.

Comment: @4386427 you're right, didn't notice that. Editing.

Comment: @qleguennec - with `str is the ascii representation of some arbitrary large integer x` you can't use any normal calculation. The input may be 1.000.000 chars long.

Comment: @4386427 yes, that's the point.

Comment: @blackpen no, as long as the digits fits into int that's fine. We can just say that x is a digit and store it in the array, then the value is x * ob ^ n.

Comment: Oh. So, the digits will be always decimal, but interpreted as per their InputBase and OutputBase.

Comment: @qleguennec - there are free code available that can deal with numbers that can't fit into standard type. Search the net for something like "Big numbers"

Comment: @blackpen yes, but not decimal, binary. They will be stored like standard numbers.

Comment: Assume `ib=16` - how would the input string look? Normal `hex` would allow `AF` but would that be `1015` in your case? And if base is 1000, would the input string have 3 decimal digits for each digit in base 1000?

Comment: @4386427 you're right, didn't think about that either. We assume 2 >= ib <= 10. Will edit.

Comment: **f(str="xxx", ib=32, ob=10) = {6,9,3,0}**. What value do you want xxx to be? Don't you want to see str also as an array (because we are not going to invent new digits for base-32 system)?

Comment: @blackpen right, that would be a final generalized version. For now, reasoning with base 2 to ten might be simpler.

Comment: Code cannot return an _array_ in C.  Detail how you expect the 
"array" and its length to be returned.

Comment: @chux - I think using -1 as an ending value would be a better choice. Then you can return a pointer to the first value in the array. Answering this question without any third party libraries will require a *lot* of code!

Comment: Does the function `f` need to be reentrant?

Comment: @YiminRong yes. I did not include too much detail about the array because I thought it wasn't relevant. We can assume that the result will be allocated with ```malloc``` and the last element in the array will be -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something to get OP started, but enough to leave OP to enjoy the coding experience.

```
// form  (*d) = (*d)*a + b
static void mult_add(int *d, size_t *width, int ob, int a, int b) {
    // set b as the carry
    // for *width elements,
    //   x = (Multiply d[] by `a` (using wider than int math) and add carry)
    //   d[] = x mod ob
    //   carry = x/ob
    // while (carry <> 0)
    //   widen d
    //   x =  carry
    //   d[] = x mod ob
    //   carry = x/ob
}

int *ql_f(const char *src, int ib, int ob) {
  // Validate input
  assert(ib >= 2 && ib <= 10);
  assert(ob >= 2 && ob <= INT_MAX);
  assert(src);

  // Allocate space
  size_t length = strlen(src);
  // + 2 + 4 is overkill, OP to validate and right-size later
  size_t dsize = (size_t) (log(ib)/log(ob)*length + 2 + 4);   
  int *d = malloc(sizeof *d * dsize);
  assert(d);

  // Initialize d to zero
  d[0] = 0;
  size_t width = 1;
  while (*src) {
    mult_add(d, &width, ob, ib, *src - '0');
    src++;
  }

  // add -1 to end, TBD code

  return d;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I wrote this with older specifications, so it's not valid any more, but it might be useful as a starting point.

The code can handle `long long` magnitudes. Going to arbitrary precision numbers in C is a big leap!

Note using `-1` as the ending marker instead of `0`. Can accept `ib` from 2 to 36 and any `ob`.

Includes example `main`.

Function `f` is *not* reentrant as-is. To make it thread-safe, it could allocate the required memory then return a pointer to it. The simplest protocol would be having the caller responsible for freeing the memory afterwards.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int *f(const char *str, int ib, int ob) {
    static int result[CHAR_BIT * sizeof(long long) + 1];
    int i = sizeof(result) / sizeof(int) - 1;
    long long l = strtoll(str, NULL, ib);
    result[i--] = -1;
    while (l) {
        result[i] = l % ob;
        l /= ob;
        i--;
    }
    return result + i + 1;
}

int main()
{
    int *x = f("1234567890", 16, 10);
    while (*x > -1) {
        printf("%d ", *x);
        x++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```